Usb wifi adapter not working on 22.04
I have Ubuntu 22.04 and USB wifi adapter Alfa Network AWUS036NH. When i connect it it keeps appearing and disappearing on network manager every second. I can see it in iwconfig:
lo        no wireless extensions.

enp3s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"Airbox-896F"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.472 GHz  Access Point: 1C:CB:99:F0:89:6F   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          
wlx00c0ca988220  IEEE 802.11  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short  long limit:2   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off

System:
  Kernel: 6.8.0-48-generic x86_64 bits: 64 compiler: N/A Desktop: Xfce 4.16.0
    Distro: Ubuntu 22.04.5 LTS (Jammy Jellyfish)
Machine:
  Type: Laptop System: LENOVO product: 80N5 v: Lenovo Yoga 500-14IHW
    serial: <superuser required>
  Mobo: LENOVO model: Lenovo Yoga 500-14IHW v: SDK0J40700 WIN
    serial: <superuser required> UEFI: Lenovo v: BDCN62WW date: 08/20/2015
Battery:
  ID-1: BAT0 charge: 20.8 Wh (100.0%) condition: 20.8/30.0 Wh (69.2%)
    volts: 8.1 min: 7.4 model: LGC L14L2P21 status: Full
CPU:
  Info: dual core model: Intel Core i3-4005U bits: 64 type: MT MCP
    arch: Haswell rev: 1 cache: L1: 128 KiB L2: 512 KiB L3: 3 MiB
  Speed (MHz): avg: 1527 high: 1696 min/max: 800/1700 cores: 1: 1130
    2: 1696 3: 1588 4: 1696 bogomips: 13567
  Flags: avx avx2 ht lm nx pae sse sse2 sse3 sse4_1 sse4_2 ssse3
Graphics:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics vendor: Lenovo driver: i915
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:02.0
  Device-2: NVIDIA GK208BM [GeForce 920M] vendor: Lenovo driver: N/A
    bus-ID: 04:00.0
  Device-3: Acer Lenovo EasyCamera type: USB driver: uvcvideo bus-ID: 2-4:4
  Display: x11 server: X.Org v: 1.21.1.4 driver: X: loaded: modesetting
    unloaded: fbdev,vesa gpu: i915 resolution: 1366x768~60Hz
  OpenGL: renderer: Mesa Intel HD Graphics 4400 (HSW GT2)
    v: 4.6 Mesa 24.1.7 - kisak-mesa PPA direct render: Yes
Audio:
  Device-1: Intel Haswell-ULT HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:03.0
  Device-2: Intel 8 Series HD Audio vendor: Lenovo driver: snd_hda_intel
    v: kernel bus-ID: 00:1b.0
  Device-3: NVIDIA GK208 HDMI/DP Audio driver: snd_hda_intel v: kernel
    bus-ID: 04:00.1
  Sound Server-1: ALSA v: k6.8.0-48-generic running: yes
  Sound Server-2: PulseAudio v: 15.99.1 running: yes
  Sound Server-3: PipeWire v: 0.3.48 running: yes
Network:
  Device-1: Broadcom BCM4352 802.11ac Wireless Network Adapter vendor: Lenovo
    driver: wl v: kernel bus-ID: 02:00.0
  IF: wlp2s0 state: up mac: <filter>
  Device-2: Realtek RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet
    vendor: Lenovo driver: r8169 v: kernel port: 4000 bus-ID: 03:00.0
  IF: enp3s0 state: down mac: <filter>
  Device-3: Ralink RT2870/RT3070 Wireless Adapter type: USB
    driver: rt2800usb bus-ID: 2-1:32
  IF-ID-1: wlx00c0ca988220 state: down mac: <filter>
Bluetooth:
  Device-1: Foxconn / Hon Hai BCM20702A0 type: USB driver: btusb v: 0.8
    bus-ID: 2-6:6
  Report: hciconfig ID: hci0 rfk-id: 2 state: up address: <filter>
    bt-v: 2.1 lmp-v: 4.0
Drives:
  Local Storage: total: 55.9 GiB used: 28.83 GiB (51.6%)
  ID-1: /dev/sda vendor: Corsair model: Corsair Force LS SSD size: 55.9 GiB
Partition:
  ID-1: / size: 54.43 GiB used: 28.82 GiB (53.0%) fs: ext4 dev: /dev/sda2
  ID-2: /boot/efi size: 299.4 MiB used: 6.1 MiB (2.0%) fs: vfat
    dev: /dev/sda1
Swap:
  Alert: No swap data was found.
Sensors:
  System Temperatures: cpu: 47.0 C pch: 42.5 C mobo: 43.0 C
  Fan Speeds (RPM): N/A
Info:
  Processes: 241 Uptime: 16m Memory: 3.74 GiB used: 1.89 GiB (50.6%)
  Init: systemd runlevel: 5 Compilers: gcc: 11.4.0 Packages: 2659 Shell: Bash
  v: 5.1.16 inxi: 3.3.13

This is output from journalctl | grep wlx00c0ca988220
lis 16 17:49:23 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775763.7418] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
lis 16 17:49:23 1jj23 ModemManager[683]: <info>  [base-manager] port wlx00c0ca988220 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1'
lis 16 17:49:23 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: wlx00c0ca988220: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
lis 16 17:49:23 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: wlx00c0ca988220: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
lis 16 17:49:23 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx00c0ca988220 disabled_11b_rates=0
lis 16 17:49:24 1jj23 kernel: rt2800usb 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca988220: renamed from wlan0
lis 16 17:49:24 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775764.4692] device (wlan0): interface index 915 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlx00c0ca988220'
lis 16 17:49:24 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775764.4916] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
lis 16 17:49:24 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775764.6998] device (wlx00c0ca988220): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
lis 16 17:49:24 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775764.7000] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lis 16 17:49:25 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775765.2919] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
lis 16 17:49:25 1jj23 ModemManager[683]: <info>  [base-manager] port wlx00c0ca988220 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1'
lis 16 17:49:25 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: wlx00c0ca988220: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
lis 16 17:49:25 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: wlx00c0ca988220: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
lis 16 17:49:25 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx00c0ca988220 disabled_11b_rates=0
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 kernel: rt2800usb 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca988220: renamed from wlan0
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775766.0251] device (wlan0): interface index 916 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlx00c0ca988220'
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775766.0368] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775766.2491] device (wlx00c0ca988220): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775766.2493] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775766.8546] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 ModemManager[683]: <info>  [base-manager] port wlx00c0ca988220 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1'
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: wlx00c0ca988220: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: wlx00c0ca988220: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
lis 16 17:49:26 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx00c0ca988220 disabled_11b_rates=0
lis 16 17:49:27 1jj23 kernel: rt2800usb 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca988220: renamed from wlan0
lis 16 17:49:27 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775767.6033] device (wlan0): interface index 917 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlx00c0ca988220'
lis 16 17:49:27 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775767.6189] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
lis 16 17:49:27 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775767.8031] device (wlx00c0ca988220): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
lis 16 17:49:27 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775767.8032] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
lis 16 17:49:28 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775768.4074] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: disconnected -> unmanaged (reason 'removed', sys-iface-state: 'removed')
lis 16 17:49:28 1jj23 ModemManager[683]: <info>  [base-manager] port wlx00c0ca988220 released by device '/sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1'
lis 16 17:49:28 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: wlx00c0ca988220: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
lis 16 17:49:28 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: wlx00c0ca988220: CTRL-EVENT-DSCP-POLICY clear_all
lis 16 17:49:28 1jj23 wpa_supplicant[5800]: nl80211: deinit ifname=wlx00c0ca988220 disabled_11b_rates=0
lis 16 17:49:29 1jj23 kernel: rt2800usb 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca988220: renamed from wlan0
lis 16 17:49:29 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775769.1516] device (wlan0): interface index 918 renamed iface from 'wlan0' to 'wlx00c0ca988220'
lis 16 17:49:29 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775769.1771] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed', sys-iface-state: 'external')
lis 16 17:49:29 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775769.3894] device (wlx00c0ca988220): supplicant interface state: internal-starting -> disconnected
lis 16 17:49:29 1jj23 NetworkManager[7072]: <info>  [1731775769.3895] device (wlx00c0ca988220): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available', sys-iface-state: 'managed')

Why is not working?
dmesg -w
[  117.115243] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 80 using xhci_hcd
[  117.260758] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070, bcdDevice= 1.01
[  117.260767] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  117.260771] usb 2-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  117.260774] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Ralink
[  117.260777] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  117.379609] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 80 using xhci_hcd
[  117.518230] ieee80211 phy74: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3070, rev 0201 detected
[  117.528521] ieee80211 phy74: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 0005 detected
[  117.528759] ieee80211 phy74: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[  117.562556] rt2800usb 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca988220: renamed from wlan0
[  117.584943] ieee80211 phy74: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[  117.585145] ieee80211 phy74: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.36
[  117.790532] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 80
[  118.310400] ieee80211 phy74: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[  118.570482] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 81 using xhci_hcd
[  118.715892] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070, bcdDevice= 1.01
[  118.715901] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  118.715905] usb 2-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  118.715908] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Ralink
[  118.715911] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  118.833727] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 81 using xhci_hcd
[  118.972458] ieee80211 phy75: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3070, rev 0201 detected
[  118.982475] ieee80211 phy75: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 0005 detected
[  118.982711] ieee80211 phy75: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[  119.017346] rt2800usb 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca988220: renamed from wlan0
[  119.039944] ieee80211 phy75: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[  119.040139] ieee80211 phy75: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.36
[  119.235828] usb 2-1: USB disconnect, device number 81
[  119.755633] ieee80211 phy75: rt2x00queue_flush_queue: Warning - Queue 0 failed to flush
[  120.009670] usb 2-1: new high-speed USB device number 82 using xhci_hcd
[  120.155165] usb 2-1: New USB device found, idVendor=148f, idProduct=3070, bcdDevice= 1.01
[  120.155174] usb 2-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[  120.155177] usb 2-1: Product: 802.11 n WLAN
[  120.155180] usb 2-1: Manufacturer: Ralink
[  120.155182] usb 2-1: SerialNumber: 1.0
[  120.274032] usb 2-1: reset high-speed USB device number 82 using xhci_hcd
[  120.413010] ieee80211 phy76: rt2x00_set_rt: Info - RT chipset 3070, rev 0201 detected
[  120.422893] ieee80211 phy76: rt2x00_set_rf: Info - RF chipset 0005 detected
[  120.423136] ieee80211 phy76: Selected rate control algorithm 'minstrel_ht'
[  120.455442] rt2800usb 2-1:1.0 wlx00c0ca988220: renamed from wlan0
[  120.473399] ieee80211 phy76: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Loading firmware file 'rt2870.bin'
[  120.473761] ieee80211 phy76: rt2x00lib_request_firmware: Info - Firmware detected - version: 0.3


Have a terminal open running dmesg -w when this is happening, it would surprise me if the USB is getting reset for whatever reason

Do you have many USB devices connected?

Wireless mouse, keyboard and wifi card

Do sudo sed -i 's/wifi.powersave = 3/wifi.powersave = 2/' /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf and reboot, see if it works

Might also want to try sed -i 's/GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="/&usbcore.autosuspend=-1 /' /etc/default/grub && sudo update-grub then reboot

Still not working
